# Load custom form into contents of a specific content type

Tags: nodes, forms

I have created a custom form through Drupal form API. Also i have added various content pages of a Content Type called "Search Pages". Those pages contain only Metadata which they are hidden. What i actually want is to show my custom form into those pages (Search Pages). How can i implement that programmaticaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output form as block, then output this block in region and set block's visibility options to show only on specific content types:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['my_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Block with form'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch($delta) {
    case 'my_block' :
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('mymodule_custom_form');
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
/**
 * Form example.
 */
function mymodule_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();
  $form['text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Place your form fields here'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Clear cache, go to blocks page (/admin/structure/block), assign your block to region. Go to your block configuration page and define Visibility settings on `Content types` tab.

Comment: Simple, straightforward, awesome!

Comment: Happy to help :)